# How to use python to generate simple int or digit password valid within duration of time?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm setting up a new server, and want to assign a simple 6 digits(or int) password for my app to my user, so that each user have my authenticated password to do something.

I know that I could use secrets.token_hex(3) or something, but it will change over everytime I run my script. I want the password not to be changed within a certain amount of time once generated, and dedicated for just one user.

my database is based on sql structure, so it will automatically add new row of data in 'site.db' file. like:

```
{'id':1, 'username':'john', 'photo':'sdlfj.png'}, {'id':2, 'username':'Mary', 'photo':'dfasdfj.png'}
```

but I want to write a new file 'assignment.db' to fetchall the data in 'site.db', and struture it like

```
`{'id':1, 'username':'john', 'password': 984657}, {'id':2, 'username':'Mary', 'password':689795}`
```

in a condition not affecting 'site.db' file

using secrets, I can do it, but since every time I run the script, all the user's password is overwritten, any simple method to do that?

Comment: You can simply _save_ your DB and then load it on startup.